# volley requestqueue returning null

Tags: java, android, json, networking, android-volley

This is my singleton class:

```
public class RequestSingleton {

    private static RequestSingleton mInstance ;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

        private RequestSingleton(Context context){
            mCtx = context;
            mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache(){

                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
        }

    public static synchronized RequestSingleton getInstance(Context context){
        if (mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new RequestSingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(mRequestQueue == null){
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
        return mImageLoader;
    }
```

This is the method from the main activity to get the posts:

```
public void getJsonPosts(){

        String url = "http://linagrey.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json";


        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject feedResponse =  response.getJSONObject("feed");
                    JSONArray entryArrayPosts = feedResponse.getJSONArray("entry");
                    BlogPost bp;
                    for (int i = 0; i < entryArrayPosts.length(); i++){
                        bp = new BlogPost();
                        //Get the entry as an array and loop through
                        JSONObject entryBlogPost = entryArrayPosts.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Get the title from the array
                        JSONObject postObject = entryBlogPost.getJSONObject("title");
                        //JSONObject postHtmlContent = entryBlogPost.getJSONObject(KEYS.POST_JSON_OBJECT_HTML_CONTENT);

                        //GET LINK ARRAY FROM JSON
                        JSONArray linkAddress = entryBlogPost.getJSONArray(KEYS.POST_JSON_ARRAY_OBJECT);

                        if(entryBlogPost.has(KEYS.MEDIA_THUMBNAIL)) {
                            JSONObject imageObjectUrl = entryBlogPost.getJSONObject(KEYS.MEDIA_THUMBNAIL);
                            String thumbnailUrl = imageObjectUrl.getString(KEYS.MEDIA_THUMBNAIL_URL);
                            bp.setmUrlThumbnail(thumbnailUrl);
                        }

                        //for loop for link array object
                        for (int j = 0;j < linkAddress.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject eachLink = linkAddress.getJSONObject(4);
                            String htmlUrl = eachLink.getString(KEYS.POST_HTML_LINK);
                            bp.setmLinkContent(htmlUrl);
                        }


                        //Get title string contained in Title Object
                        String title = postObject.getString(KEYS.POST_TITLE);
                        Log.v(TAG, "OBJECTS HAVE THIS PROPERTIES: " + i + " " + title);


                        //Set Properties Gotten
                        bp.setmTitle(title);

                        Log.v(TAG, "OBJECTS HAVE THIS PROPERTIES: " + i + " " + bp.toString());
                        //Add a blog post Object to the Arraylist
                        postArrayList.add(bp);


                    }
                   // Log.v(TAG, "Arraylist SIZE " + postArrayList.size());

                    for(BlogPost posts : postArrayList){
                        Log.v(TAG, posts + " ");
                    }

                    // Toast.makeText(this.,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        });
        RequestSingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);
     }
```

This is the error output, i have no idea on how to interpret these error messages:

```
05-31 08:44:14.880 2653-2653/wait.com.linasblog E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: wait.com.linasblog, PID: 2653
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wait.com.linasblog/wait.com.linasblog.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
                                                                      at wait.com.linasblog.RequestSingleton.getRequestQueue(RequestSingleton.java:51)
                                                                      at wait.com.linasblog.RequestSingleton.<init>(RequestSingleton.java:24)
                                                                      at wait.com.linasblog.RequestSingleton.getInstance(RequestSingleton.java:44)
                                                                      at wait.com.linasblog.MainActivity.getJsonPosts(MainActivity.java:204)
                                                                      at wait.com.linasblog.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I posted a similar question earlier but got no answers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the request singleton class is getting initialized. All the fields are static but they haven't been set to anything so they are still null. try a `RequestSingleton rs = new RequestSingleton();` before you try to add to request queue. Even better override the application class so that it initialized the request singleton class on startup.

EDIT:
I don't know if it is a best practice but its at least something else to try if you are still having trouble. This overrides the Application class and uses the custom Class. It will initialize Volley when your app starts.

```
public class VolleyApplication extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = VolleyNetworkTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private static VolleyNetworkTask sInstance;
    private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public synchronized static VolleyNetworkTask getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

And the put this in your manifest in the manifest tag

```
    <application 
        android:name=".VolleyApplication"
        .../>
```

Get the request queue
    `VolleyApplication.getRequestQueue();`